# Heapsorting algorithm

Tags: java, heap, heapsort

so I have a program that performs a heap sort and I have a remove element function. I do this by taking the last element all the way on the right side and then replace the n-th element with it. To maintain the sort, I then bubble the element down to its correct place in the heap. My friend doesn't seem to think that this will work. will it?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: I dont have the program on hand to test it out unfortunately. Its just kind of a hypothetical at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heapsort is using max-heap, each time, you need to switch the root node, which is the max one, with the `n`th element, then put the max element into result list from right to left.

Then, bubble the element down to its proper position, and decrease the heap's size from n to n-1.

Then, the new root node of new heap is the max element among the remaining n-1 elements. Just recursively switch root element with the `n-1`th element, and again put the max element to the result list, decrease heap's size by 1 until the heap's size is 0